# getting list from many to one mapping HQL

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, hql

I cannot seem to get a list from a many to one relationship I have going below I have both my entities and my data access object in the long run I need something like this`select * from test,session where session.starttime =? AND session.id=test.sessionid;`

This is my first entity with fullSession being my many to one object.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
public class Test {

    public Test() {
        Date date = new Date();
        startTime = new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime());
    }


    //the order of this models variables is coupled to the order in they appear in the view//
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "testid")
    private int testId;

    @Column(name = "intensityfeedback")
    private Integer intensityFeedback;

    @Column(name = "sampleid")
    private String sampleId;

    @Column(name = "panelistid")
    private String panelistId;

    @Column(name = "starttime")
    private Timestamp startTime;

    /*
    @Column(name = "sessionId")
    private int sessionId;
    */

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="sessionid")
    private FullSession fullSession;

    public FullSession getFullSession() {
        return fullSession;
    }

    public void setFullSession(FullSession fullSession) {
        this.fullSession = fullSession;
    }


    @Transient
    private int randomNumber;

    @Embedded
    private List<Sample> samples = new ArrayList<Sample>();

    public String getPanelistId() {
        return panelistId;
    }

    public void setPanelistId(String panelistId) {
        this.panelistId = panelistId;
    }

    public int generateRandomNumber(int numSamples) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        randomNumber = rand.nextInt(numSamples) + 1;
        return randomNumber;
    }

    public List<Sample> getSamples() {
        return samples;
    }

    public void setSamples(List<Sample> samples) {
        this.samples = samples;
    }

    public int getTestId() {
        return testId;
    }

    public void setTestId(int testId) {
        this.testId = testId;
    }

    public int getRandomNumber() {
        return randomNumber;
    }

    public void setRandomNumber(int randomNumber) {
        this.randomNumber = randomNumber;
    }

    public String getSampleId() {
        return sampleId;
    }

    public void setSampleId(String sampleId) {
        this.sampleId = sampleId;
    }

    public Integer getIntensityFeedback() {
        return intensityFeedback;
    }

    public void setIntensityFeedback(Integer intensityFeedback) {
        this.intensityFeedback = intensityFeedback;
    }

    public Timestamp getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public void setStartTime(Timestamp startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }
```

This is my second entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="session")
public class FullSession {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int sessionId;

    @Column(name="starttime")
    private Timestamp startTime;

    @Column(name="endtime")
    private Timestamp endTime;



    public int getSessionId() {
        return sessionId;
    }
    public void setSessionId(int sessionId) {
        this.sessionId = sessionId;
    }

    public Timestamp getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }
    public void setStartTime(Timestamp startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }
    public Timestamp getEndTime() {
        return endTime;
    }
    public void setEndTime(Timestamp endTime) {
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }
```

finally here is my data access object

```
package iff.spring.dao;

@Repository
public class TestDaoImpl implements TestDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<Test> getTests() {
        List<Test> tests;
        // get the current hibernate session
        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        // create the query
        Query<Test> query = currentSession.createQuery("from Test where FullSession.id = sessionId ", Test.class);
        // execute the query and get the result list
        tests = query.getResultList();
        // return the list// get the current hibernate session
        return tests;
    }

    @Override
    public void saveTest(List<Test> tests) {
        // get current hibernate sessions
        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        for (Test test : tests) {
            currentSession.save(test);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the question?  Anyway, your HQL is not even a valid.  And, a `ManyToOne` relationship is of course not going to give you a list: it is `~ToOne`, so, only "one"

Comment: not sure what you mean but each of my Tests has one session hence many to one but yes my hql was wrong first time using hibernate I acheived my solution shown below

Comment: You asked "getting list from many to one" and I simply said it does not make sense. It is your obligation to ask clearly and concisely. Turned out you were simply asking HQL syntax, then why were you providing bunch of unrelated information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error I acheived my solution with the following query

`Query<Test> query = currentSession.createQuery("select t from Test t INNER JOIN t.fullSession f where f.startTime = ?",Test.class)`;

Comment: You don't need inner join here as it is implicitly provided. `from Test t where t.fullSession.startTime = :startTime` gives you a more readable form

Comment: And in your original question you haven't even provided the parameter to the query

Comment: Apologies thank you for the usefull feedback. I kept seeing this syntax :startTime and didint know what it's my first time using an ORM

Comment: This is something you can learn from simply reading introductory topics of Hibernate.  Please get a book and really read it.  I don't think learning simply by wild guessing is an effective way.

Comment: If I had time I definitely would currently i'm strapped for time and rapidly developing this app as an internship.I decided to use Hibernate because I thought it would speed up development and is an industry standard didint realise it would complicate normal sql queries.But yes your right it took me a bit of digging through stackoverflow to find how to setup my enviorment to do a proper join query.

Comment: Learning basics first is going to save you time. One day of study will probably save you from 10 problems with similar level as this. It is really surprising people think development is something you can do simply by intuition

Comment: The issue is I thought ORM was just a simplification for mapping classes to database tables I didint realise it was drastically different.But again thankyou for the advice I'm graduating this fall so I can use it :).

Answer (score 0):

When you use the spring annotations，you need add configuration in your applicationContext.xml file.

<context:component-scan base-package="pack.pack"/>  //pack.pack eg：com.dao

then,

You need load applicationContext.xml file.

code:
ApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

I suggest you paste your console error information!

Comment: Theres something wrong with the HQL 
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: sessionFactory is null ?

Comment: Do you add configuration in your applicationContext.xml file? And load it!

Comment: web.xml file need  configuration  about spring and spring mvc!

Comment: ok I got this bit working there was actually some null valeus in my database which I forgot were there .any idea how to write this statement in hql select * from test,session where session.starttime =? AND session.id=test.sessionid;

Comment: in hql: from test,session where session.starttime =? AND session.id=test.sessionid;

Comment: @yunwei1237 suggesting unnecessary theta join in HQL is probably one of the worst suggestions